# group by integer range Django & posgres

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-postgresql

i have a table which i would like to group by integer range (ages).
table for example:

```
Name   Age
John   21
Steve  24
Dan    29 
Mike   31
```

my expected result is to group the name by age ranges for example [21-28] [29-33]
so what i'll get is the following result:

```
[21-28] [29-33]
  John    Dan
  Steve   Mike
```

i was playing around with the annotate function of Django but couldn't figure it out so far.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to annotate which age group it belongs to use [**`conditional annotation(Case)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) like this:

```
from django.db.models import Case, CharField, Value, When

Person.objects.annotate(
     age_group = Case(
          When(age__range=[21, 27], value=Value('21-27')),
          When(age__range=[29, 33], value=Value('29-33')),
          default=Value('No group'),
          output_field=CharField(),
     )
).values('age', 'age_group')
```

Comment: in django 2.2 it's  When(age__range=[21, 27], then=Value('21-27')), instead of  When(age__range=[21, 27], value=Value('21-27')),

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a finite number of groups, why not do a query for each and every one?

```
21_28_group = Person.objects.filter(age__gte=21).filter(age__lte=28)
29_33_group = Person.objects.filter(age__gte=29).filter(age__lte=33)
```

Comment: that's what i used so far but the performance wasn't good enough. went for annotate since i thought it could be achieved in 1 query to db